# Invalid arguments passed join()

Tags: php, join, mysqli

So I made this script that should fetch an array using `mysqli_fetch_array` and `mysqli_query` it all works fine, and no error shows up, but then after I change something, using another function, for example, If I change the mood, nickname or whatever, it shows an error

```
Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed in Main.php on line 526
```

Iv'e been trying to fix this using a `while loop` and the same thing happens

```
$info = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, nickname, mood, credits, colour, curhead, curface, curneck, curbody, curhands, curfeet, curflag, curphoto, rank * 146 FROM `sync_users` WHERE id='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $raw[5]) . "';"), MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$client->sendPacket("%xt%gp%-1%" . join("|", $info) . "%");
print str_replace('Array', '', print_r($info, true));
```

I tried asking a few other friends who knew php well and they were unable to give me a solution as well.

Comment: It might be unrelated to your problem but it never hurts to do error checking when you run a query against the database. BTW, `print_r()` is not as reliable as `var_dump()` as debugging tool.

Comment: yeah it doesn't really affect anything but I hate seeing errors even though I do prefer seeing it because I don't want buggy functions and stuff, for some reason I prefer `print_r` because it's more cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

One or more elements of the array isn't a string. Either cast the offending fields in the query, or pass all the fields through `strval()` first.

Comment: The fields, not the array.

Answer (score 0):

### Here goes a lesson on basic debugging:

If a PHP function complains for the input parameters, it would be a good idea **to verify these parameters.** So, adding

```
var_dump($info);
```

to your code will most likely output `(bool)false`

Which lead us to believe that SQL query returned no rows, and so it's time to debug the query.

Hope it helps

Comment: Did not solve anything unfortunately :( the `join()` error still pops up, should I suppress the error using `@`?

Comment: it is not intended to "solve", mind you. It is intended to give you **information** to solve. Which nobody know at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

First of all **don't use mysql_* functions because are deprecated, try [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) for example**

I think that if `mysqli_fetch_array` returns an empty resultset then the `join` will fail because mysqli returns a FALSE

Perhaps it will be your problem

Comment: I thought Mysql extensions are deprecated and not Mysqli extensions.

Comment: Yes, you're right, i thought that mysqli extension are deprecated too.